# HTML / TypeScript display multiple checkbox values in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angularfire2

The problem is that i want to be able to select multiple checkboxes, and on the click of the Testing button, display the selected boxes in the console. The problem here is that im only using one checkbox that displays in several rows. I´m using angular 2 with material design components and angular fire 2.

```js
//TypeScript
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk';

@Component({
    selector: 'waybill-billing',
    templateUrl: './waybillbilling.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./waybillbilling.component.css']
})
  

export class WaybillBillingComponent implements OnInit {
  checked = false;
  @Input('id') waybillId: string;
  displayedColumns = ['status', 'type', 'articleId', 'description', 'amount'];
  dataSource: FirebaseDataSource;
  
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){}  
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new FirebaseDataSource(this.db, this.waybillId);  
  } 


}

export class FirebaseDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private waybillId: string) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): FirebaseListObservable<any[]> {
    this.items = this.db.list('xxx/pieces/' + this.waybillId);
    console.log(this.items);
    return this.items;
  }

  disconnect(){

  }
}
```

```html
//HTML
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-typography">

    <div> ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="status">
      <md-header-cell class="body-2" *cdkHeaderCellDef> Status </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell class="body-1" *cdkCellDef="let row"> 
        <md-checkbox></md-checkbox>
      </md-cell>
    </ng-container>  
    </div>  

    <!-- Type Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="type">
      <md-header-cell class="body-2" *cdkHeaderCellDef> Type </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell class="body-1" *cdkCellDef="let row"> 
        <md-chip-list><md-chip selected="true" color="blue">{{row.type}}</md-chip></md-chip-list>
      </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Article Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="articleId">
      <md-header-cell class="body-2" *cdkHeaderCellDef> Art.nr </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell class="body-1" *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.articleId}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Description Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="description">
      <md-header-cell class="body-2" *cdkHeaderCellDef> Beskrivning </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell class="body-1" *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.description}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Amount Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="amount">
      <md-header-cell class="body-2" *cdkHeaderCellDef> kg/st </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell class="body-1" *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.amount}} kg </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
    <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>
    
    
  </md-table>
  
<button (click)="test()" md-button>Testing</button>
</div>
```

> 

1. strong text

Comment: From your question it's not very clear what you try to achieve, mostly why don't you put multiple checkboxes if you need them, what is preventing you to do so?

Comment: Because the checkbox is created for each table row that´s created, which depends on how many rows there are in every case. The amount of checkboxes will never be the same!

Comment: so your question is how to do that?

Comment: It´s now automatically creating checkboxes for each row. But i wanna know how to combine these boxes in TypeScript, so i can read which boxes are checked of them!

Comment: You class is typescript which goes with Angular and the tags of your question, but the template is in angularjs.

Comment: I´m quite a beginner here so did not know how to change the template!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of which checkboxes is checked:

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="select">
  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Status </md-header-cell>
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
    <md-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                 (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row.$key) : null"
                 [checked]="selection.isSelected(row.$key)">
    </md-checkbox>
  </md-cell>
</ng-container>
```

In your code:

```
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/material';

selection = new SelectionModel<string>(true, []);
```

Here is a plunker where you probably can find some good stuff for your needs...

[md-table with checkboxes](https://plnkr.co/edit/EU3BBlViWpPf2NJW4PXx?p=preview)